# Why does Linux not deliver data to applications when the packets come via a hotspot?

Tags: networking, networkmanager

My goal is to intercept traffic with a MITM proxy. To do this, I configured my laptop to host a Wi-Fi hotspot, connected the smartphone, started the proxy, and configured the smartphone to use my laptop as proxy on this Wi-Fi network.

The host IP is `10.42.0.1` and the client `10.42.0.2`. The proxy is listening on port 8080, any interface. It shows up correctly in `netstat` and I can `netcat` to it from localhost. The Android phone is configured to proxy via `10.42.0.1` port 8080.

From the phone, I can ping `10.42.0.1`; in Wireshark I see the echo requests coming in and the responses going out.

When the phone sends a TCP or UDP packet, however, the system does not respond. When listening on the hotspot with netcat on UDP and sending UDP data from the phone, the data is not delivered to netcat. I can see the packet, with data, incoming in Wireshark, but the terminal remains blank. When listening on TCP, I can see in Wireshark the SYN packet coming in from the phone, but it is never acknowledged (no SYN+ACK response).

The hotspot (`10.42.0.1`) clearly has ARP and a route back or ICMP echo responses would not go out. There is no host firewall installed. The issue persists after a reboot.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question I realized that, although I knew it couldn't be a firewall because I had none installed, and it couldn't be iptables because they wouldn't persist past a reboot, I realized that I did not actually check that no iptables rules were set.

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:isakmp
ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     ah   --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8528
```

It turns out that something, probably NetworkManager in its infinite wisdom, decided to add some rules for us, happy to unexpectedly supply a firewall.

A workaround is to kill some rules and reset the default policy:

```
# iptables -L --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
3    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
5    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
# iptables -D INPUT 5
# iptables --policy INPUT ACCEPT
```

I cannot find any reference to any of this in the NetworkManager documentation or even source code. I don't know what this port 8528 is that it seems to allow by default (it's not registered nor referenced anywhere) and I can't quickly find the relevant code that calls iptables, or find any relevant settings to stop it from firewalling the connection. Perhaps NetworkManager calls some other software that subsequently installs this?